# Delete duplicate rows using SQL and window function

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, delete-row

In the following table

```
create table employee (emp_id integer, emp_name varchar(50), dept_id integer);
insert into employee values (1,'bob william',1);
insert into employee values (2,'scott tiger',1);
insert into employee values (3,'amit gupta',1);
insert into employee values (4,'vijay sinha',1);
insert into employee values (5,'miller jones',3);
insert into employee values (6,'adam clark',3);
insert into employee values (7,'smith stuart',3);
insert into employee values (8,'james ward',4);
insert into employee values (9,'adam black',4);
insert into employee values (7,'smith stuart',3);
insert into employee values (8,'james ward',4);
insert into employee values (9,'adam black',4);
```

I am looking for duplicates rows based on emp_name column.
I tried the following code:

```
WITH CTE_Table AS 
(SELECT *, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp_name ORDER BY emp_name) AS RN
FROM employee
)
DELETE FROM CTE_Table
WHERE RN > 1
```

I get the following message: 'ERROR:  relation "cte_table" does not exist
LINE 6: DELETE FROM CTE_Table'

Please help. I am using PostgreSQL with PG Admin 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deleting from a CTE is not possible**

But i recommend you instead of it to work with `temp tables`;

Your `CTE` as `TEMPORARY TABLE` will look so;

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY emp_name ORDER BY emp_name) AS RN
FROM employee;
DELETE FROM temp_table where RN > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If it is not too much to ask, do you know how to delete duplicate row affecting original table?

Comment: of course  replace `DELETE FROM temp_table where RN > 1;` to `DELETE FROM employee where emp_id in (select emp_id from temp_table  where RN > 1);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE to identify the duplicates and then `DELETE` based on the result of the CTE;

```
WITH CTE_Duplicates AS (
    SELECT emp_id, emp_name, dept_id
    FROM employee
    WHERE emp_id NOT IN (
        SELECT MIN(emp_id)
        FROM employee
        GROUP BY emp_name
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
)
DELETE FROM employee
WHERE emp_id IN (SELECT emp_id FROM CTE_Duplicates);
```